# Finding system with infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

The question asks to find equation for which the system has infinitely many solutions.

The system is:
\begin{cases}
       -cx + 3y + 2z = 8\\
         x      + z  = 2\\
        3x + 3y + az = b
\end{cases}

How should I approach questions like this?
I tried taking it to row reduced echelon form but it got kind of messy.

The answer is supposed to be:
 $$a - c -5 = 0$$  and $$b- 2c +2 = 0$$

Comment: The determinant has to be zero --- that gives you a start.

Comment: By inspection, you can find values of $c$, $a$, and $b$ so that the third equation is the same as the first.

Comment: Another simple solution is possible here. If you add the first and the second equation, the resulted equation must be equal to the third. From this you can find coeffitients. However this solution work here, it need not work in other similar tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do row reduction; consider the matrix
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-c & 3 & 2 & 8 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 3 & a & b
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
-c & 3 & 2 & 8 \\
3 & 3 & a & b
\end{array}\right]\quad\text{swap 1 and 2}\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 2+c & 8+2c \\
0 & 3 & a-3 & b-6
\end{array}\right]\quad\text{reduce first column}\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 2+c & 8+2c \\
0 & 0 & a-c-5 & b-2c-14
\end{array}\right]\quad\text{reduce second column}\\
\end{align}
The system has infinitely many solutions if and only if the last row is zero, that is
\begin{cases}
a-c=5\\
b-2c=14
\end{cases}

Comment: on the second operation you did 'reduce first column', what operation did you do on row 2?

Comment: @JeanFerreira I summed the second row with the first multiplied by $c$, which is a legal operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cramer's rule. If the determinant:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
-c && 3 && 2 \\
1 && 0 && 1 \\
3 && 3 && a 
\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

then the system has either no solution or infinite amount of solutions. If all three determinants:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
8 && 3 && 2 \\
2 && 0 && 1 \\
b && 3 && a 
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
-c && 8 && 2 \\
1 && 2 && 1 \\
3 && b && a 
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
-c && 8 && 2 \\
1 && 2 && 1 \\
3 && b && a 
\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

Then the system has infinite amount of solution. Can you solve it on your own now?